# QSlider Multiple Sliders

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm using QT 5 and was wondering the best way to achieve something similar to Microsoft gradient selector. I have thought of a couple of different way of achieving this but i'm not sure of the best approach, so was wondering if anyone else has tried to create one so far.

Keen to hear ideas.

[image]

Comment: maybe [Qt-Color-Widgets](https://github.com/mbasaglia/Qt-Color-Widgets) can give you an ideas. There is GradientSlider, A slider that has a gradient background

Comment: You could check [QxtSpanSlider](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxtspanslider.html) for inspiration. It is a slider with two handles: https://bitbucket.org/libqxt/libqxt/src/696423b68972fc9edae318558b8ce26dc187cc40/src/widgets/qxtspanslider.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default